# Unable to turn on device - see whit pixeled screen

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode

I tried to flashify my ZTE z5 with a not suitable recovery for this phone (TWRP 2.8.6) and now I am unable to turn it on.
I can only see a white pixeled screen and not able to get into recovery mode (using vol down + power).

ADB does not recognize the phone (when write "adb devices"in cmd), but windows does recognize it as "Android", but I do not have access to the local drives (I do not see the NX503A in the "Devices and drives" section)

Is there a way to rescue it?

Thank you!!

Gil

Comment: I don't understand. You can't boot into neither system nor recovery? Where do you try to use adb then?

Comment: Hi @SarpSTA, I am trying to use adb in windows cmd.

Comment: I understood that. What I don't understand is in what state is the phone? (download mode, recovery mode, system)

Comment: I am afraid that neither. :(
As soon as I connect the phone to the computer with a usb cable (even when the battery is unplugged) or try to turn in on, it gets stuck in a white pixeld screen.

Comment: @SarpSTA, like in this picture:http://i.imgur.com/pdkw3ex.png

Comment: Can you try to use the steps from [here](http://www.hardreset.info/devices/zte/zte-nx501-nubia-z5/#download-mode-and-ftm-mode) to get your phone in **download mode**

Comment: @SarpSTA Something happend!!

the screen turned off however I see many drives created!
one of them looks like the actual internal storage, another one has a folder called image and all others I cannot access.

Comment: See it where? On cmd?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32556/discussion-between-gil404-and-sarpsta).

Comment: I'm sorry. He can't help any further as well. My opinion is that it is bricked for good.